# using python and pandas printing index instead of actual value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an excel sheet as shown in the picture bellow,

[image]

I want to print the index instead of printing the value it self and the index should be unique per sheet,
I tried:

```
import string
import pandas as pd
text=pd.read_csv("testme.csv")
print(text.index[0:])
```

but unlike the normal print its not returing any index of the values it returns:

**RangeIndex(start=0, stop=7, step=1)**

any solutions? I want it to be printed as table same as the input but index instead of value
this is what I get for normal print: [image]

I want it to print a new column showing the index of the words.

Comment: have you tried with enumerate?

Comment: no, but will check them now, I want the print to be a table with words and frequency but index inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
print(df.reset_index().drop(columns=df.columns).to_string(index=False))                                                                                                              

 index
     0
     1
     2
     3
     4
```

Comment: how can I add this output to a new column of my table called index ? any ideas

Comment: oh, you should just be able to do df['index'] = df.index

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(text.index.values)
```

That will print an array from 0 to N instead of the RangeIndex which just describes the start and end numbers.

Comment: it is returning the index but not in the shape of table as a normal print, do you have any solutions so that it will return in in a shape of table with words and frequency but index inside

Comment: What does `print(text)` give you?  Can you post the actual CSV content in your question (or at least the first few lines)?